# Tips for golfing in Objective C

Tags: code-golf, tips, c

Although on codingame.com, Objective C and C are two of the best golfing languages there, so I would like to know some of the best golfing methods (although I am a python person, I am currently trying to learn C++/C)

I am looking for general ways/tips to golf one's code (so please don't post tips such as "remove comments" and so on)

Please post each tip as a separate answer.